# Positioning two instances of "it" in a question, is one option more likely to be confusing, ambiguous, or mis-understood than the other?

Tags: word-order, it-its-itself

I'm torn how to position the two instances of "it" in this question. I believe that both sentences are acceptable and convey the same meaning, but I'm not sure which is more likely to be confusing, ambiguous, or mis-understood.

Does one stand out as the better title for a Stack Exchange [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/111060/16035)? Is there a standard rule at play here that I should know about?

> A: Is honey really a supersaturated solution? Does heating to un-crystalize redissolve it or melt it?
>
> B: Is honey really a supersaturated solution? Does heating to un-crystalize it redissolve or melt it?

I suppose I could also get rid of one instance all together as well:

> C: Is honey really a supersaturated solution? Does heating to un-crystalize redissolve or melt it?

Comment: I may need some help with proper tagging.

Comment: I find all three options perfectly clear and natural, with a slight preference for B. In natural conversation, I think I’d probably use _it_ three times: “Does heating to decrystallise it redissolve it or melt it?”. (Note the double L and the prefix in _decrystallise_ – I’ve never heard of _un_-crystallising honey, but decrystallising honey is a reasonably common phrase.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet thanks for the reassurance, and for a new word for me; *decrystallise*

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I might even use four instances of the pronoun: *Does heating **it** to un-crystalize **it** redissolve **it** or melt* ***it***?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet could that be suitable for as an accepted answer?